# where is developer option in samsung sm-t531

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

Hi i have a samsung tablet model sm-t531 with android 4.4.2 which don't have developer option in settings can any one tell me where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android version 4.2 and higher, the Developer options menu is hidden by default. To show the Developer options menu, touch Menu > Settings > More > About phone. Scroll down to Build number, and touch Build number seven times. The menu option will then appear under Settings > More > Developer options.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your phone `Settings` Once there, tap on `About phone` and hit the `build number` `7 times` to unlock things. Now go back to `Settings` and developer options will be available.